# multipart rest api request and implementation to kotlin android

Tags: rest, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, multipart

I have managed to make a rest api with the following request
**employee_id, leave_duration, leave_type_id, note, attachments, date**

i have tried in postman and it saved successfully, the problem is when i implement it to kotlin android studio it always error and returns **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"**

this is an example of my postman when it works
[postman preview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S-KywsRXg7W-Va09NQu51zoV6jxnuQHk/view?usp=sharing)

[postman preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d581G.jpg)

here's my code in Apiservice Interface

```
@Multipart
    @POST(Constans.ADD_LEAVE_DATA)
    suspend fun submitLeaveRequest(
        @Part("employee_id") employeeId: RequestBody,
        @Part("leave_duration") leaveDuration: RequestBody,
        @Part("leave_type_id") leaveTypeId: RequestBody,
        @Part("note") note: RequestBody,
        @Part("date") date: RequestBody,
        @Part attachments: List<MultipartBody.Part>
    ): Response<ResponseUmumLeave>
```

this is my Repository code

```
    suspend fun adddataleave(employee_id: RequestBody, leave_duration:RequestBody, leave_type_id:RequestBody, note:RequestBody, date:RequestBody, attachments:List<MultipartBody.Part>?):Response<ResponseUmumLeave>{

        return ApiRetrofit2.apiService.submitLeaveRequest(employee_id,
        leave_duration,
        leave_type_id, note, date, attachments!!
        )
    }
```

here is my ViewModel code

```
    private val addleaveRepository = addleaveRepository()

    val _createdata = MutableLiveData<Response<ResponseUmumLeave>>()
    val createdata: LiveData<Response<ResponseUmumLeave>> get() = _createdata

    private val viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    fun submitLeaveRequest(
        employee_id: RequestBody, leave_duration: RequestBody, leave_type_id: RequestBody, note: RequestBody, date: RequestBody, attachments:List<MultipartBody.Part>?
    ) {
        uiScope.launch {
            try {
                val res =addleaveRepository.adddataleave(employee_id,
                    leave_duration,
                    leave_type_id, note, date, attachments!!)
                _createdata.value = res
                // Lakukan sesuatu dengan response dari API jika diperlukan
                // Misalnya, simpan response ke LiveData agar bisa diobservasi di UI
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Tangani error jika terjadi
                Log.e("LEAVEDATA", e.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

then this is the code that I put in the fragment

```
            attachments = selectedFiles.map { uri ->
                uri.let {
                    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                        "attachments[]",
                        it.name,
                        it.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                    )
                }
            }
            if (attachments != null) {
                val employeeIdRequestBody = userid!!.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val leaveDurationRequestBody =
                    ciptype!!.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val leaveTypeIdRequestBody =
                    idtype.toString().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val noteRequestBody = note.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val dateRequestBody = date.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())

                val request = dataleaveRequest(
                    employeeIdRequestBody,
                    leaveDurationRequestBody,
                    leaveTypeIdRequestBody,
                    noteRequestBody,
                    dateRequestBody,
                    attachments
                )

                addleaveViewModel.submitLeaveRequest(employeeIdRequestBody,
                    leaveDurationRequestBody,
                    leaveTypeIdRequestBody,
                    noteRequestBody,
                    dateRequestBody,
                    attachments)
                Log.e("id", userid.toString())
                Log.e("tipe-cuty", idtype.toString())
                Log.e("time-cuty", ciptype.toString())
                Log.e("tanggal", date)
                Log.e("file", attachments.toString())
            }

        }

//observe data response
addleaveViewModel.createdata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Log.d("Response Code", "${it.code()}")
            if (it.isSuccessful && it.code() == 200) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data Berhasil Disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                val errorMessage = it.message()
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error $errorMessage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("errorleavedata", errorMessage)
            }
        }
```

and this is my ApiRetrofit2 class

```
    lateinit var context: Context

    fun init(context: Context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    private val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient by lazy {
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(AuthInteceptor()) // Add the AuthInterceptor here
            .build()
    }

    private val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
    }

    val apiService: ApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
```

i want to get a response from my server side api, and it should be successful in saving the data but it's not, i'm sure it's because of the multipart attachments, hope it gets resolved quickly